# record video call in a room only when user enters record button in twilio

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twilio, twilio-api

What I am trying to do is to record the video call between one and another user that is going on. The video record will be started once user click on record button. However, I am getting the following issue

```
Unable to fetch record↵Invalid RecordingSid parameter
```

I am using rails for api and reactjs for frontend. In rails side i did the following

```
def record
    @client = client_authenticate()
    puts params["room_sid"]
    # RM5XXXXXXX
    recording = @client.video.recordings(params["room_sid"]).fetch
    puts recording.track_name
end
```

front end side

```
const Controls = ({ handleLeaveRoom, handleMute, handleRecord, mute }) => (
  <Wrapper>
    <Icon icon={mute ? faMicrophoneSlash : faMicrophone} size="2x" onClick={handleMute} />
    <HangCall icon={faPhone} size="2x" onClick={handleLeaveRoom} />
    <Icon icon={faDesktop} size="2x" />
    <Icon icon={faCloud} size="2x" onClick={handleRecord} />
  </Wrapper>
);

const handleRecord = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE}/twilio/record`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ room_sid: room.activeRoom.sid }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      });
      console.log("requested");
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      console.log("jsonResponse", jsonResponse);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("e", e);
    }
  }
```

In a nutshell, I want to record the ongoing video call when user hits the record button to the cloud but getting above issue. I send the sid which we get when we join the room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I can find nothing in the documentation that says you can start a recording part way through a video. From what I can see, you need to [create the room via the REST API and set the `recordParticipantsOnConnect` parameter to `true`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#post-list-resource) and that will record a participant once they join.

In your code, on the Rails side, you are trying to request a recording that doesn't yet exist using the Room SID, which is the identifier for the room not for a recording. That's why that request is failing.

There's no API endpoint to start a recording part way through.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the mistake i did but I want to clear one confusion and take your suggestion. You are saying i cant record the video call between two participants when they themselves want to record the video by clicking on record button like i wanted instead it will be recorded as soon as they join in a room, right? If that's the case, can i then create another room  and set `recordParticipantsOnConnect` to true when record button is clicked?

Comment: You could certainly do that, though you'd need to handle moving your participants from the existing room to the new one that is recording.

Comment: hi @philnash - I noticed in the API docs on the `Room` class there are `recordingStarted` and `recordingStopped` flags.  Are you aware of any way to use these flags, or something like the, to toggle the recording? Taking it another route, the wording here https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript-v1-getting-started#enabling-room-recordings sounds as if the recording option might be enabled per participant (on the connect).  Know of anything there? As always, your answers are much appreciated, as are your github examples :)

Comment: @inyourcorner I'm not aware of any way to toggle recordings right now. I imagine that these events are possibly foreshadowing future functionality, but I can't promise anything because I don't actually know myself. 

Answer (score 0):

I think this is now possible via the recording rules API: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/recording-rules

I've experimented with this and found that recording starts when I do:

```
curl -XPOST 'https://video.twilio.com/v1/Rooms/RMxxx/RecordingRules' --data-urlencode Rules='[{"type": "include", "all": true}]' -u 'xxx:xxx'
```

And stops when I do the same command with `include` replaced by `exclude`.